# how to format JSON object array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I am struggling with a tough requirement where I don't know how to deal with

I received one Array as below:

```
[{
    "student": "21_A_1",
    "sport": "badminton"
}, {
    "student": "21_C_1",
    "sport": "badminton"
}, {
    "student": "21_A_2",
    "sport": "badminton"
}, {
    "student": "21_B_1",
    "sport": "football"
}, {
    "student": "21_A_2",
    "sport": "football"
}]
```

Requirement: convert it to an array with format :

```
[{
    "student": "21_A_1",
    "sport": ["badminton"]
}, {
    "student": "21_C_1",
    "sport": ["badminton"]
}, {
    "student": "21_A_2",
    "sport": ["badminton","football"]
}, {
    "student": "21_B_1",
    "sport": ["football"]
}]
```

I found that [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10) library has a feature "group by" returned quite closed result but not as expectation:

```
_.groupBy(array, 'student');
```

Result:

```
{
    "21_A_1": [{
        "student": "21_A_1",
        "sport": "badminton"
    }],
    "21_C_1": [{
        "student": "21_C_1",
        "sport": "badminton"
    }],
    "21_A_2": [{
        "student": "21_A_2",
        "sport": "badminton"
    }, {
        "student": "21_A_2",
        "sport": "football"
    }],
    "21_B_1": [{
        "student": "21_B_1",
        "sport": "football"
    }]
}
```

Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: Better that you construct your own algo than using lodash for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to map the grouped items with their `sport` propery and build new objects with the grouping informations.

```js
var array = [{ student: "21_A_1", sport: "badminton" }, { student: "21_C_1", sport: "badminton" }, { student: "21_A_2", sport: "badminton" }, { student: "21_B_1", sport: "football" }, { student: "21_A_2", sport: "football" }],
    grouped = _(array)
        .groupBy('student')
        .map((group, student) => ({ student, sport: _.map(group, 'sport') }))
        .value();

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick solutions, all are working, however, I marked this is as answer because I am using lodash. I don't know which one is the best practices, so if you guys have any best practice please keep sharing it. Because the array can be up to thousands items.

Answer (score 2):

We can use '.reduce' function of array and aggregate result as below

```js
var test = [{
    "student": "21_A_1",
    "sport": "badminton"
}, {
    "student": "21_C_1",
    "sport": "badminton"
}, {
    "student": "21_A_2",
    "sport": "badminton"
}, {
    "student": "21_B_1",
    "sport": "football"
}, {
    "student": "21_A_2",
    "sport": "football"
}]
const result = test.reduce((res,x)=>{
   res[x.student] = res[x.student] || { student:x.student,sport:[]}
   res[x.student].sport.push(x.sport)
   return res;
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) combined with [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```js
const data = [{"student": "21_A_1","sport": "badminton"}, {"student": "21_C_1","sport": "badminton"}, {"student": "21_A_2","sport": "badminton"}, {"student": "21_B_1","sport": "football"}, {"student": "21_A_2","sport": "football"}];
const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, c) => ((a[c.student] = a[c.student] || {student: c.student, sport: []}).sport.push(c.sport), a), {})
);

console.log(result);
```